# How do I sort a long or int datatype inside a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

The following works fine sorting three columns which are DateTime and strings

```
data = new List<WorkItem<object>>(rows);
//....Add items to list
data.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    int result = DateTime.Compare((DateTime)x.Column1, (DateTime)y.Column1);
    if (result == 0)
        result = string.Compare((string)x.Column2, (string)y.Column2);
    if (result == 0)
        result = string.Compare((string)x.Column3, (string)y.Column3);
    return result;
});
```

How can I also include sorting of long and int data types in the lambda sort expression?

The following gives an `'long' does not contain a definition for 'Compare'`

```
data.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    int result = DateTime.Compare((DateTime)x.Column1, (DateTime)y.Column1);
    if (result == 0)
        result = string.Compare((string)x.Column2, (string)y.Column2);
    if (result == 0)
        result = string.Compare((string)x.Column3, (string)y.Column3);
    if (result == 0)
        result = long.Compare((long)x.Column15, (long)y.Column15);
    return result;
});
```

The columns are generic types T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `long` can't be `null`, you can simply:

```
result = ((long)x.Column15).CompareTo((long)y.Column15);
```

Or, when in doubt:

```
result = Comparer<long>.Default.Compare((long)x.Column15, (long)y.Column15);
```

Works correctly for all the basic types and for all the types that support `IComparable<>` or `IComparable`, and handles correctly `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

long type does indeed not contain a definition for Compare. Compare returns a negative value if first object is lower than second one, 0 if they are equal and a positive value if first one is greater than the second one. Given this you can just return the difference of the two long values. Modified code below:

```
data.Sort((x, y) =>
{
int result = DateTime.Compare((DateTime)x.Column1, (DateTime)y.Column1);
if (result == 0)
    result = string.Compare((string)x.Column2, (string)y.Column2);
if (result == 0)
    result = string.Compare((string)x.Column3, (string)y.Column3);
if (result == 0)
    {
        long r = (long)x.Column15 - (long)y.Column15;
        result = r == 0 ? 0 : r < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }
return result;
});
```

Make sure to change Column15 to whatever you need there.

Comment: @xanatos Why would you cast it to int if the values are long?

Comment: Try compiling it. `result` is an `int`... And I'm not even sure it would be a good idea to do the cast.... Wait... it is plainly wrong... see https://ideone.com/Fpvwiv for example.

Comment: You are right about the result being int so that won't work like that. Thanks. Edited the answer. That should work now.

Comment: If you want, you can even write `result = Math.Sign(r)` that does exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for letting me know. Didn't knew that.